# Working with .txt file like with database

Tags: android, java-8

I`m coding app, which scan barcode and save information in .txt. I thought what android have some class like TStringList, but it seems like I`m wrong.
 After app read QR code it must search string, wat contain it raw data in .txt. If .txt contain data, then I`am open activity, what show raw data and some information (for exemple first name, secondname) from this string in TextView`s. If .txt contain no scaned data information, then I`am open activity, where user print associated information in EditText and save information in string with raw data QR code. So how do I searchinng data in strings? And how parse string? I think it will be question like "how insert string in line with some numer" in future. Anybody direct me on classes, codes, sources about this.

Comment: Be more specific about your problem

Comment: Instead of using a `StringList` take a look at the generic [ArrayList<T>](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp)

Comment: thanks. that still exist))

Comment: I can`t understand, arraylist.contents returns true if all string match, or just a part of string?

Comment: Which function are you using to check?

Comment: I thought I asked a specific question. What function to use for search? Or do you need to write a function to search for?